# SparkSQL Converting Integer to MM-DD-YYYY

Tags: datetime, pyspark, casting

The following code outputs a table:

```
df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("dbfs:/FileStore/shared_uploads/*********/*********")
df1.registerTempTable("df1")
display(df1)
```

The table has a 'Date' column in the form of a big integer:

- 20220716
- 20220717
- etc.
- etc.

Then, I want to use pyspark to output a column in the form MM-DD-YYYY but it is returning null for DATE_FINAL.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

oe_seq = sqlContext.sql(""" 
to_date(cast(Date as string), 'MM-dd-yyyy') as DATE_FINAL,
from df1

""")
oe_seq.registerTempTable("oe_seq")
display(oe_seq)
```

How can I get the column to be in the form 'MM-dd-YYY' in PySpark??

Answer (score 0):

you have tried to format using to_date but to_date is used to convert into date from string

for formatting in desired form you can do using date_format like below

```
spark.sql("select date_format(to_date(cast(date as string),'yyyyMMdd'),'MM-dd-yyyy') as DATE_FINAL from df1")
```

Comment: Will this cast the column as a datatype 'date' ???

Comment: no the datatype will be string by default but we can cast it to date by explicit cast --


spark.sql("select cast(date_format(to_date(cast(date as string),'yyyyMMdd'),'MM-dd-yyyy') as date) as DATE_FINAL from df1")

Comment: this is returning null for the entire column

Comment: oh yes direct cast won't work so you can either choose between datatype as date or custom date format which will be stored as string

Comment: so what do I have to do to turn column into a date type? right now it is a string after running the query

Comment: As I said if you want to have your desired format then use the query in answer or if you want date as datatype of Date_final then -- spark.sql("select to_date(cast(date as string),'yyyyMMdd') as DATE_FINAL from df1")